# Struggling with onItemClick in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listview

I've tried a number of different ways to get this to work.  I have 4 swipe-able tabs using fragment class, when I extend the fragment add a list I cannot get the onListItemClick to work, I have tried to use a listfragment but that conflicts with fragment ive tried implements onitemclick and I have tried numerous toher methods but I always end up with errors.  The error I get here is onitemclick is never used.
Can someone help!!

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class LeagueOne extends Fragment {


String[] teams = {"Barnsley", "Blackpool", "Bradford City",
        "Burton Albion", "Bury", "Chesterfield", "Colchester United", "Coventry City",
        "Crewe Alexandra", "Doncaster Rovers", "Fleetwood Town", "Gillingham", "Millwall",
        "Oldham Athletic", "Peterborough United", "Port Vale", "Rochdale", "Scunthorpe United",
        "Sheffield United", "Shrewsbury Town", "Southend United", "Swindon Town", "Wallsall", "Wigan Athletic"};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item, container, false);
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, teams);
    ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}




protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    if (position == 2) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),BradClass.class);;
        startActivity(intent);

}}}
```

Comment: H:\DrawerWithSwipeTabs\app\src\main\java\com\androidbelieve\drawerwithswipetabs\TabFragment.java
Error:(71, 31) error: incompatible types
required: Fragment
found:    LeagueOne
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Answer (score 0):

1- Your `Fragment` must extend `ListFragment` in order to work with the `onListItemClick` method. Which means that you have to define a `ListView` in your Fragment's layout who's `id` is **@android:id/list**.

2- Then in your `fragment`'s code, you can easily access the `ListView` using the `getListView()` method

3- Set its adapter using `setListAdapter(adapter)` instead of `lv.setAdapter(adapter);`

4- Delete a semi colon from the end of this line :

`Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),BradClass.class);;`

**ALTERNATIVELY**, instead of the process above, you could create a custom `ArrayAdapter`, pass in the `Activity`'s **context** to its constructor, and set the listeners on the `ListView`'s items from within it.

Comment: Hi I am getting an error in the TabFragment class that I was getting before when attempting this, it says incompatible types required android.support.v4.fragment found then a link to my package and class com.android.drawerwithtabs.leagueone

Answer (score 0):

> Try using the below code.

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
  @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int     position, long id) {
//your logic for onclick goes here
  }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` and then set it to `ListView`

```
public class LeagueOne extends Fragment implements  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
```

Then set this reference to `onItemClickListener()`

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(this)
```

Then implement the `onItemClick` method

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      //your logic for onclick goes here
}
```